# How can I make point on an image or (Part of an image) clickable in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

The problem is I have an web app with the below image and every blue point in that image i clickable by adding <map> tag and detecting the coordinates on each point to assign a javascript function..

#### Image

[image]

This screen I want to develop it using flutter is that functionality available in flutter ?

Please note I try that but with no luck!

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return CustomPaint(
    painter: MultiClickableShapePainter(),
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Image.asset('assets/CarInspector.png'),
        InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            print('by');
          },
        ),
        InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            print('hi');
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

```
class MultiClickableShapePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // Draw the first clickable shape on the canvas
    Paint paint1 = Paint()..color = Colors.red;
    Path path1 = Path();
    path1.addRect(const Rect.fromLTRB(150, 150, 250, 400));
    canvas.drawPath(path1, paint1);

    // Draw the second clickable shape on the canvas
    Paint paint2 = Paint()..color = Colors.blue;
    Path path2 = Path();
    path2.addRect(const Rect.fromLTRB(75, 75, 130, 200));
    canvas.drawPath(path2, paint2);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Is there any suggestions solutions ?

Comment: The approach given by @Felipe below on of the best and easiest ways to go about this. Please check it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Positioned` inside `Stack` to position the small circles

Place the `child` of `Positioned` inside `InkWell`

#### Approach

```
Stack
 |_ Positioned     Circle 1
   |_ InkWell
     |_ Text 
 |_ Positioned     Circle 2
   |_ InkWell
     |_ Text 
 |_ Positioned     Circle 3
   |_ InkWell
     |_ Text 
 |_ Positioned     Circle 4
   |_ InkWell
     |_ Text
```

#### Code

```
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
      children: [
        Image.network(
            'https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.XU225Remieh8Qmb2HXf4AwHaEa?pid=ImgDet&rs=1'),
        Positioned(
            left: 220,
            bottom: 80,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 12,
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    print("Pressed 1");
                  },
                  child: const Text('1')),
            )),
        Positioned(
            right: 24,
            bottom: 140,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 12,
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    print("Pressed 2");
                  },
                  child: const Text('2')),
            )),
        Positioned(
            right: 230,
            top: 52,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 12,
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    print("Pressed 3");
                  },
                  child: const Text('3')),
            )),
        Positioned(
            left: 53,
            top: 89,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 12,
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    print("Pressed 4");
                  },
                  child: const Text('4')),
            ))
      ],
    ));
```

#### Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Krishna Acharya,
It works fine, but I have a question do you use a tool to detect the place of the blue circles you putted, I mean the left and bottom properties ?

            Positioned(
                left: 200,
                bottom: 80,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 12,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        print("Pressed 1");
                      },
                      child: const Text('1')),
                )),

Comment: If the post works for you. Please consider accepting the answer ✅ by click the tick button  ✔

Comment: Krishna Acharya
Sure It's works fine :) 
Thanks a lot!